# Image upload not working with DRF and React

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I am trying to implement image upload functionality using React and DRF. I believe it is not working properly. When I tried to upload image with correct format, it is working fine. But when I tried to upload invalid image, in response it is giving me a long error other than I mentioned in code.

```
class ArticleManager(models.Manager):
    def active(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ArticleManager, self).filter(draft=False).filter(publish__lte=timezone.now())


class Articles(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    short_title = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, default='not available')
    content = models.TextField()
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # publish = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    publish = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    read_time = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
    like = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='images/articles/')
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='images/articles/thumbnail/')

    objects = ArticleManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-timestamp', '-updated']

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
        if not self.pk:
            self.slug = create_slug(Articles, self.title)
            if self.image:
                image_type = self.image.name.split('.')[-1]
                self.image.name = '{}.{}'.format(self.slug.replace('-', '_'), image_type)
                if not self._get_thumb():
                    raise ValueError("Thumbnail could not be created")   # I am expecting to get this error

        return super(Articles, self).save(
            force_insert=force_insert,
            force_update=force_update,
            using=using,
            update_fields=update_fields
        )

    def _get_thumb(self):
        image = Image.open(self.image)
        image.thumbnail((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)

        thumb_name, thumb_extension = os.path.splitext(self.image.name)
        thumb_extension = thumb_extension.lower()

        thumb_filename = thumb_name + '_thumb' + thumb_extension

        if thumb_extension in ['.jpg', '.jpeg']:
            FTYPE = 'JPEG'
        elif thumb_extension == '.gif':
            FTYPE = 'GIF'
        elif thumb_extension == '.png':
            FTYPE = 'PNG'
        else:
            return False  # Unrecognized file type

        # Save thumbnail to in-memory file as StringIO
        temp_thumb = BytesIO()
        image.save(temp_thumb, FTYPE)
        temp_thumb.seek(0)
        self.thumbnail.save(thumb_filename, ContentFile(temp_thumb.read()), save=False)
        temp_thumb.close()
        return True
```

error I am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\GIT\personal-blog\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "E:\GIT\personal-blog\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "E:\GIT\personal-blog\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "E:\GIT\personal-blog\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\GIT\personal-blog\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\GIT\personal-blog\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 497, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "E:\GIT\personal-blog\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 457, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "E:\GIT\personal-blog\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 468, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "E:\GIT\personal-blog\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 494, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\GIT\personal-blog\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py", line 190, in post
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\GIT\personal-blog\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 19, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "E:\GIT\personal-blog\backend\articles\api\views.py", line 62, in perform_create
    serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
  File "E:\GIT\personal-blog\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 213, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "E:\GIT\personal-blog\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 932, in create
    instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)
  File "E:\GIT\personal-blog\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\GIT\personal-blog\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 422, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "E:\GIT\personal-blog\backend\articles\models.py", line 58, in save
    raise ValueError("Thumbnail could not be created")
ValueError: Thumbnail could not be created
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a check in the server to validate whether you upload a image, if not, send a failure status code back to the front end. Change the front end code to handle failure.